# How to find $X$ and $Y$ using $Z$ between two points in $3$ dimensions?

Tags: geometry

How to find $X$ and $Y$ using $Z$ between two points in $3$ dimensions?

$(1, 1, 1)$, $(X, Y, 1.5)$ and $(2, 2, 2)$ $\leftarrow$ this is the line

$X = 1.5$

$Y = 1.5$

I am looking for the formula

Using answer below:

$z_p=t_pz_1+(1-t_p)*z_2$, replace $t_p$ with $x$

$z_p=xz_1+(1-x)+z_2$

we know $z_p=1.5$, $z_1=1$, $z_2=2$, put it into the formula

$1.5=x*1+(1-x)+2$

$1.5=x+2-2x$

$2x-x=2-1.5$

$x=0.5$, $(x=t_p)$,

In case you need it using $t_p$

$t_p = (z_2-z_p)/(z_2-z_1)$;

Comment: Create a linear equation? In this case, $(x,y,z)=t\cdot(1,1,1)+(1,1,1)$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$. You can use this to solve. (I found the triple to multiply $t$ by by taking the difference of the two points, and the constants is simply one of the points.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the line through points $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ will have parametric equation

$x=tx_1 + (1-t)x_2\\y=ty_1 + (1-t)y_2\\z=tz_1 + (1-t)z_2$

If you know any one of the three co-ordinates for a point $P$ on this line then you can solve for $t$ and so find the other two co-ordinates at $P$.

Comment: I confused by the sentence 'you can solve for t and so find the other two coordinates at P'.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi Suppose the co-ordinates of $P$ are $(x_P, y_P, z_P)$ and $t$ has value $t_P$ at $P$. If you know $z_P$ then you can find the value of $t_P$ from the equation $z_P = t_Pz_1 + (1-t_P)z_2$. Once you know the value of $t_P$ you can find the values of $x_P$ and $y_P$.

Answer (score 1):

Your unknown point is on the line segment between $A$ and $B$. The points on that segment have the form $tA + (1-t)B$. Since  you know the third coordinates you can find $t$, then use $t$ to find the other two coordinates.

In your example this is easy: $t = 1/2$. You have the midpoint of the segment.